# On Twilio, is it possible to configure a phone # so that it produces a "No Answer" status when called?

Tags: twilio

So, yes, on Twilio I am trying to troubleshoot a problem when a outgoing phone call ends up in "No Answer" status.  The system works fine when the call ends up in "Complete" status (which is the most common case, as this happens even with voicemail). Recently one outgoing call ended up in "No Answer" and the system did not follow the escalation process (to call the secondary person).

Now I was looking into creating a test phone # that does not answer and that does not have a voicemail.

I already tried to create a new phone number and put no webhook (this causes it to immediately hang up).

Is this possible with twilio?  What about other services?

Answer (score 1):

A `DialCallStatus` of `no-answer` will be triggered when the `timeout` attribute of the  verb is reached. So, if you have the following TwiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="1">415-123-4567</Dial>
</Response>
```

the call will actually timeout after approximately 6 seconds since Twilio adds a 5 second buffer. This will trigger the `DialCallStatus` of `no-answer` to be sent to the action URL.